# Android Fragment, передача ссылки в браузер

Tags: java, android

Имеется ссылка, которую необходимо открыть в браузере. Как это можно сделать?
У Activity - intentом, а у фрагментов как?

Comment: Тем же интентом. В чём проблема-то - не знаете где взять контекст?

Answer (score 1):

код

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://vk.com"));
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```